# Gwan load balancer setup

Tags: g-wan

I'm considering to use Gwan for a backend game server. Although Gwan can handle lot of requests, I would want to make it scalable automatically. Gwan has elastic load balancer. Are there examples on how should that be setup at code/deployment?

Comment: Yes hardware is better, but g-wan on linux is supposed to be incredibly fast, and its free unlike Azure.  This is a great question for potential start-ups where bandwidth isn't the major concern, but redundancy, scalability and budget are.

Answer (score 0):

imo, load balancing is a function of the cloud or data center you are working with and not gwan.

in microsoft's azure which is good as it offers linux VMs you set up an endpoint (which is essentially a port like 8080) as a load-balanced endpoint that terminates to the port on each VM.

set up your gwan to port 8080.
set up a loadbalanced endpoint on port 8080.
point the loadbalancer to the gwan port of 8080.

clients then hold sessions with either vm1 or vm2.

auto-scaling is a function of azure's availability set.

im sure a similar process is offered on Amazon and Rackspace.